# Estimating $\max_{\|u\|=1} \frac{ E\left[\langle u\cdot x\rangle ^4\right]}{E\left[\langle u\cdot x\rangle ^2\right]}$

Tags: pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control

Suppose we have access to samples of $x$ distributed according to unknown multivariate Gaussian in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Estimate the following quantity:
$$\max_{\|u\|=1} \frac{ E\left[\langle u\cdot x\rangle ^4\right]}{E\left[\langle u\cdot x\rangle ^2\right]}$$

I'm inspired by stochastic power iteration which gives a good estimate of $\max_{\|u\|=1}E\left[\langle u\cdot x\rangle ^2\right]$ by iterating $u \leftarrow x x^T u; u \leftarrow u/\|u\|$ a small number of times, considerably less than $d$ when distribution has small effective rank.  Is there a modification for the problem above?

Comment: any information on the law of $x$? Is it continuous? Tails?

Comment: I need to apply this in practice for unknown $x$, but for theory, it would be nice to see something that works for Gaussian $x$

Comment: Is $x$ centered?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\si\sigma\newcommand\Si\Sigma$If $x$ is centered, then $u\cdot x\sim N(0,\si_u^2)$, where $\si_u^2:=u\cdot\Si u$ and $\Si$ is the covariance matrix of $x$. So,
$$\frac{E(u\cdot x)^4}{E(u\cdot x)^2}=\frac{3\si_u^4}{\si_u^2}=3\si_u^2.$$
So,
$$\max_{\|u\|=1}\frac{E(u\cdot x)^4}{E(u\cdot x)^2}=3\|\Si\|^2,$$
where $\|\Si\|$ is the spectral norm of $\Si$.

---

Generally, if $x\sim N(\mu,\Si)$, then $u\cdot x\sim N(\mu_u,\si_u^2)$, where $\mu_u:=u\cdot\mu$, so that $\mu_u^2\le\|\mu\|^2$ for any unit vector $u$. So,
$$\frac{E(u\cdot x)^4}{E(u\cdot x)^2}=\frac{3\si_u^4+\mu_u^4+2\si_u^2\mu_u^2}{\si_u^2+\mu_u^2}\le3\si_u^2+\mu_u^2$$
and hence
$$\max_{\|u\|=1}\frac{E(u\cdot x)^4}{E(u\cdot x)^2}\le 3\|\Si\|^2+\|\mu\|^2.$$

Comment: Thanks....I'm dealing with a non-centered case, and was looking for a computational approach to improve on the upper bound. As an intermediate step, I was looking for a iteration $v\leftarrow f_x(v)$ where $E[\ldots \circ f_x\circ f_x \circ f_x \circ 1] \to u$ where $u$ is the maximizer

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov : I don't understand notations in your comment. What is $v$? What is $f_x$? What are the left and right arrows?

Comment: $f_x(v)$ is a random function of arbitrary vector. The other arrow indicates that iterating $f_x$ on some starting point converges to $u$, the maximizer, in expectation as the number of iterations grow to infinity. An example of such iteration is $f_x(v)=(x x^T v)/\|x x^T v\|$ which appears to converge to  $\operatorname{argmax}_uE[\langle u \cdot x\rangle^2]$ in this fashion

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov : Your $f_x(v)$ and all its iterations will just be $\pm x/\|x\|$. I don't see how this could work and what your point here is.

Comment: If $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ are copies of random variable $x$ then as $n\to \infty$ we have $E[f_{x_n}\circ \ldots \circ f_{x_1} \circ \mathbf{1}]$ converging to $\operatorname{argmax}_u E[\langle u\cdot x\rangle^2]$. I want to find analogous $g_x$ such that $E[g_{x_n}\circ \ldots \circ g_{x_1} \circ \mathbf{1}]$ converges to $\operatorname{argmax}_u \frac{E[\langle u\cdot x\rangle^4]}{E[\langle u\cdot x\rangle^2]}$

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov : How do you prove the convergence? Also, why do you need all this? The expectation of the random iteration seems very hard to compute, whereas the maximized ratio is given explicitly and seems computationally easy to maximize. Also, if more is known about $\Sigma$ and $\mu$ (such as, say, $\|\mu\|$ being much greater than $\|\Sigma\|$), I think one can give good enough bounds on the $\max$.

Comment: Your formula involves $u$, how do I estimate it? I have $d\approx 10^{12}, \frac{\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma)}{\|\Sigma\|} < 100$, with only access to samples of $x$, which calls for online estimation. Iterating $g_x$ from the previous comment is known to rapidly converge to the maximizer of $\max_v E[\langle v\cdot x\rangle^2]$ in this setting, so I can use your formula for the centered $x$. It's Eq 1 of [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.02456) with convergence proof. Now I need a way I can use for uncentered

Comment: (i) In your post, you did not say that your $d$ is so large. (ii) The [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.02456) should have been referred to right away. (iii) Your updates seem quite different from those in the paper. In particular, importantly, the updates in the paper do not involve taking expectations. (iv) Again, if more is known about $\Sigma$ **and** $\mu$, then I think one can give good enough bounds on the $\max$.